# Group Array of Objects by key and sum values from mongoose aggregation result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query result from a mongoose aggregation query that I need to further process, or at best do it in the aggregation itself.

The aggregation looks like this

```
 result = await TokenBalance.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    { ethervalue: { $gte: minBalance } },
                    {
                        ethervalue: { $lte: maxBalance }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        { $limit:limit }

    ])
```

This returns an array of Objects of this format

```
 {
    "_id": "61013d6dda7d7c0015af5ccf",
    "balances": [
     {
       "address": "0x1fc3ddeb035310930a444c0fa59c01618d5902af",
       "symbol": "HBTC",
       "balance": 5.21419339e-10,
       "usdvalue": 0.000020969961637162402
     },
     {
       "address": "0x1fc3ddeb035310930a444c0fa59c01618d5902af",
       "symbol": "NSBT",
       "balance": 1.258566,
       "usdvalue": 27.427343477595258
     },
     {
       "address": "0x1fc3ddeb035310930a444c0fa59c01618d5902af",
       "symbol": "CRV",
       "balance": 517.985955847106,
       "usdvalue": 806.7017064052314
     },
     {
       "address": "0x1fc3ddeb035310930a444c0fa59c01618d5902af",
       "symbol": "USDT",
       "balance": 0.003469,
       "usdvalue": 0.003470159747979122
     }
   ],
   "address": "0x1fc3ddeb035310930a444c0fa59c01618d5902af",
   "ethervalue": 0.7604598621232733,
   "createdAt": "2021-07-28T11:20:13.927Z",
   "updatedAt": "2021-07-28T11:20:13.927Z",
   "__v": 0
},
```

What I need, is the "balances" property to be processed as grouped by symbol and for each of these symbols sum the balance and usdvalue fields.

I would prefer this do be done in the aggregation if possible, but I can not seem to get it right, even not in pure nodejs.

I want the result to be like this:

```
[
 {
  symbol: USDC, balance: xxx, usdvalue: yyy
 },
 {
  symbol: USDT, balance: zzz, usdvalue: jjj
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below approach,

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the `balances` array
- `$group` by `symbol` and sum `balance` and `usdvalue`
- `$addFields` to rename `_id` field to `symbol` and  and remove `_id` field

```
result = await TokenBalance.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { ethervalue: { $gte: minBalance } },
        { ethervalue: { $lte: maxBalance } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$balances" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$balances.symbol",
      balance: { $sum: "$balances.balance" },
      usdvalue: { $sum: "$balances.usdvalue" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      symbol: "$_id",
      _id: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  { $limit:limit }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DQ04Lh2ZOdo)